# How come nothing is showing up on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Nothing at all is showing up on the screen. I've had this problem with another project but forgot how to fix it. Here is what I have so far.

```
#----- To-Do -----#
#      Init       #
 
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.display.set_caption('Cake Clicker')
RESOLUTION = (192, 108)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*
window = pygame.display.set_mode (RESOLUTION, pygame.SCALED)

#Functions
def Quit():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            
def Images(Back):
    window.fill((255,255,0))
    backgrounds = []
    backgrounds.append(pygame.image.load('ClickerBackground.png'))
    window.blit(backgrounds[Back], (192 / 2, 108 / 2))

running = True
background = 0
while running:
    Quit()
    Images(0)
pygame.quit()
```

I tried changing variables, not using a function and just putting it under the engine or whatever, yet nothing has worked, I feel as if it is an easy fix i'm not seeing.

Comment: You need to add `pygame.display.update()` to the end of your `while` loop or `Images()` function.

Comment: @importrandom Thanks! I knew I’d be something stupid like that. How do I say you answered my question correctly?

Comment: I'm glad that fixed your problem, you can create an [answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This question will probably get closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: In addition to the above you need to make `running` global ( with `global running`) in `Quit()` as else quitting pygame will not work and put some delay into the `while running:` loop (best use therefore `pygame.time.Clock()`.

Comment: @Claudio I’ll do that, thanks man.

Comment: Another recommendation: load your images only once, outside your `Images()` function. It probably doesn't have a significant effect now, but if in the future you're doing a similar thing with lots of images, it may have a speed impact. For coordinates, you typically need an integers, so you should use integer division [`//`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/)

Comment: @importrandom yeah ill do that too. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

My code was missing a pygame.update() function!